# Debugging and resolving a Rails interlock issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've managed to consistently reproduce a deadlock situation (I believe) despite following the following resources:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html#executor
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27025#issuecomment-260169414

The following code will deadlock:

```
Parallel
        .map(domains, in_threads: 4) do |domain|
          Rails
            .application
            .executor
            .wrap { EcommEnrichmentUtils.qualified_domain(domain) }
        end
        .compact
    end
```

The contents of `EcommEnrichmentUtils` essentially sends out some HTTP requests.

Output for `/rails/locks`

```
Thread 0 [0x1a518 sleep]  No lock (yielded share)
  Waiting in start_exclusive to "load"
  may be pre-empted for: "load"
  blocked by: 1, 2

/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:108:in `sleep'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait_for_cond'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:116:in `wait_while'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:220:in `wait_for'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in start_exclusive'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:82:in `block in start_exclusive'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:77:in `start_exclusive'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:39:in `load_interlock'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:402:in `require_or_load'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:558:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `const_missing'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in validated_url_without_subdomain'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:89:in `each'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:89:in `detect'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:89:in `block in validated_url_without_subdomain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:102:in `block (2 levels) in get'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:189:in `calc'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:102:in `block in get'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:204:in `block in synchronized'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronized'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:102:in `get'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:68:in `validated_url_without_subdomain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `validate_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:270:in `block in _on_method_added'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/typed_service_objects/ecomm_enrichment_utils.rb:22:in `qualified_domain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `validate_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:270:in `block in _on_method_added'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (3 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:88:in `wrap'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (2 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:507:in `call_with_index'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:518:in `with_instrumentation'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:366:in `block in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:215:in `block (4 levels) in in_threads'


---


Thread 1 [0x1a52c sleep]  Sharing
  blocking: 0

/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronized'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:102:in `get'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:68:in `validated_url_without_subdomain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation_2_7.rb:703:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation_2_7.rb:703:in `block in create_validator_method_medium1'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/typed_service_objects/ecomm_enrichment_utils.rb:22:in `qualified_domain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `validate_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:270:in `block in _on_method_added'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (3 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:88:in `wrap'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (2 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:507:in `call_with_index'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:518:in `with_instrumentation'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:366:in `block in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:215:in `block (4 levels) in in_threads'


---


Thread 2 [0x1a540 sleep]  Sharing
  blocking: 0

/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:199:in `synchronized'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/zache-0.12.0/lib/zache.rb:102:in `get'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/services/domain_helper.rb:68:in `validated_url_without_subdomain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation_2_7.rb:703:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation_2_7.rb:703:in `block in create_validator_method_medium1'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/typed_service_objects/ecomm_enrichment_utils.rb:22:in `qualified_domain'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `validate_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:270:in `block in _on_method_added'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (3 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:88:in `wrap'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:374:in `block (2 levels) in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:507:in `call_with_index'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:518:in `with_instrumentation'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:366:in `block in work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:215:in `block (4 levels) in in_threads'


---


Thread 3 [0x15f7c sleep]  No lock (yielded share)

/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:217:in `value'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:217:in `map'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:213:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:213:in `block in in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:211:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:211:in `in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:360:in `work_in_threads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/parallel-1.20.1/lib/parallel.rb:281:in `map'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:370:in `block in normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:368:in `normalize_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `bind_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:161:in `validate_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.9465/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:270:in `block in _on_method_added'
/Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/app/controllers/ecomm_analyze/collections_controller.rb:177:in `bulk_add_domains'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.1/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionview-6.1.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/flipper-0.22.1/lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:77:in `memoized_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/flipper-0.22.1/lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:42:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rollbar-3.2.0/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:25:in `block in call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rollbar-3.2.0/lib/rollbar.rb:145:in `scoped'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rollbar-3.2.0/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rollbar-3.2.0/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/web-console-4.1.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/web-console-4.1.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/web-console-4.1.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/web-console-4.1.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-contrib-2.3.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:19:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/request_store-1.5.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_locks.rb:41:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:393:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/webpacker-5.4.3/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.0/lib/rack/proxy.rb:63:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/server.rb:447:in `process_client'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/puma-5.5.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to parse this or what a reasonable next step is.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

It seems that this is an issue with the Zache gem.
See this line:

https://github.com/yegor256/zache/blob/master/lib/zache.rb#L206

This I believe introduces an external sleep.

I was able to fix my code by wrapping the method BEFORE called `zache.get`

Something like this:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.interlock.permit_concurrent_loads do
        Rails
          .application
          .executor
          .wrap do
            zache.get(url, lifetime: 10.minutes) do
              # do work here
            end
          end
      end
```